# Retrieve certain element with class via an index

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/9G6NM/

```
console.log($('.square').css('background-color')); // red
console.log($('.square')[1].css('background-color')); // error
console.log($('.square')[2].css('background-color')); // error
```

How can retrieve the green and blue square's attributes via jquery?

Comment: The brackets array accessor return DOM elements and not jQuery elements. As many already suggested, use .eq() See [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
console.log($('.square').css('background-color'));
console.log($('.square').eq(1).css('background-color'));
console.log($('.square').eq(2).css('background-color'));
```

The problem is that [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is a method of jQuery objects. But if you use bracket notation to access individual elements, you get the "real" ones, without any jQuery wrapping.

Alternatively, you could:

- Wrap it again in a jQuery object (expensive, not recommended):

  ```
  $($('.square')[1])
  ```
- Use vanilla-js to get the style:

  ```
  $('.square')[1].style.backgroundColor; // Only to get inline styles
  getComputedStyle($('.square')[1]).backgroundColor;
  ```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness, even if that thoroughness appears to include somewhat, uh, *questionable* approaches (re-wrapping a DOM node from a jQuery collection with jQuery..? *Why?*).

Comment: @DavidThomas I have included a warning. However, if performance is important, jQuery shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Oriol IMO David's point is valid. **Using jQuery shouldn't preclude using it efficiently.**  Just because a framework might itself be somewhat heavy, one should avoid compounding the problem with code that is easily made more efficient.  For example, the overhead of jQuery will be minor in comparison to non-jquery code that might be written to scale poorly O(n^2).  Regardless, it's an excellent answer and +1 for updating your answer to explain DOM object vs jquery object.

Comment: @AaronLS Yes, his point is valid, that's why I included a warning.

Answer (score 3):

Use `eq()`:

```
console.log($('.square').eq(1).css('background-color'));
```

The square brackets retrieve the DOM node from the jQuery collection, not the jQuery object at that index point.

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$($('.square')[1]).css('background-color')
```

The .css requires a jquery object, and the `[1]` gives you a DOM object, so you must use `$()` to convert it to jquery object (not sure if this is correct terminology)

http://jsfiddle.net/9G6NM/2/

Comment: oops there you are again, I didn't know why you'd deleted your comment so made it an answer haha

Comment: I was not 100% sure it'd work, but then I decided to jsfiddle it to verify and convert to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option appears to be this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9G6NM/1/

```
console.log($($('.square')[0]).css('background-color')); // red
console.log($($('.square')[1]).css('background-color')); // green (dark)
console.log($($('.square')[2]).css('background-color')); // blue
```

Comment: It is an option, but it's a pointlessly expensive option, creating a jQuery object from a collection of elements, retrieving a DOM node from that collection and then wrapping that with jQuery...